# Async/Await in JavaScript for Quiz Creation

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I've searched and haven't found the answer to this, but if it has been posted and I missed it, sorry for the duplicate. I'm creating a simple quiz game in JS, and got a prototype working: you select one of four levels, and then it asks you questions. All questions will have the same group of potential answers, since it's a quiz on reading sheet music, and there are only 7 notes that they can potentially choose. In the prototype, I was using a prompt and then passing the note name they typed in, but I'm now looking to do it with buttons instead, which I think is highly preferable. So far, I have the following: 4 functions, 1 for each level. That's how I had it working on the prototype, and it worked like a charm. I also have a checker function, which is passed one note from the button clicked:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('a');" role="button">A</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('b');" role="button">B</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('c');" role="button">C</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('d');" role="button">D</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('e');" role="button">E</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('f');" role="button">F</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:checker('g');" role="button">G</a>
```

The problem is, I need the function to wait for it before then updating the score, etc. And that's where I'm having trouble. Right now, I have this, using the easy level as an example. All variables not shown are global.

```
async function easy()
{
  var answer="";
  num=Math.floor(Math.random() * 22);
  if(num<1) num = 1;
  document.getElementById('noteContainer').innerHTML = '<img src="assets/' + img[num-1] + '.png"</img>';
  await checker();
  function pt()
  {
    if(correct)
      {
       streak+=1;
       score+=1;
       document.getElementById('scoreContainer').innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score + '/' + streak;
       document.getElementById('resultContainer').innerHTML = 'Nicely done!';
       correct = false;
       easy();
    }
    else {
      streak+=1;
      document.getElementById('scoreContainer').innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score + '/' + streak;
      document.getElementById('resultContainer').innerHTML = 'Incorrect. That note was ' + notes[num-1].toUpperCase() + '.';
      easy();
     }
  }
}

async function checker(answer)
  {
    if(answer == notes[num])
    {
      correct = true;
    }
else {

    }
}
```

I'm sure my code is not the world's most efficient, but I am wondering if anyone knows what's going wrong here, or if I'm just completely going about it in the wrong way. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why you would need the async/await for? The function `checker` doesn't seems to do an asynchronous operation...

Comment: I only figured that I would need to since it didn't work without anything async-related added. If it just needs to be used as a regular function, then I guess I have some other problem in the code that I need to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Although wouldn't the easy() function need to wait until checker() has been run since it depends on a global boolean variable that is changed based upon the checker() result? Otherwise, it would just assume false all the time.

Comment: The whole implementation seems wrong to me. For now, you can have the answer button call the checker, update the global variable, and then call `easy()`. You can also call easy with a parameter to determine if the answer was correct. Also, what is `pt()` Why is there a function within a function?

Comment: The pt() function was a remnant from when I was using a prompt to get the answer, though was still probably unnecessary. And I agree that it could be implemented much more efficiently, but my issue in doing this was that I needed a way for the program to know what level the player wanted, and I didn't see a way to do that except for starting a specific method after the player chose a level, and then having it call itself to go to a new question. But thank you, I agree that there's probably a far better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know whats the point of using async/await here. You could achieve this without those specific type of function. If you wish to learn where/how to use async/await, I would recommend this [article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65#:%7E:text=Async%2FAwait%20was%20created%20to,the%20Promise%20will%20be%20resolved.).

Meanwhile, this is something I came up with very quickly using jQuery. If you end goal is to have user select a level, answer bunch of question and show user's score, this will do the trick.

You need create a Game object and let it hold the information such as level, score and question. You could also have it store all of the questions as well rather than what I am doing it.

Again, there are multiple ways to do this, this is one of them.

```js
let game = null;
reset();

const quiz = [{
  questions: ['Random Question #1 (Answer: A)', 'Random Question #1 (Answer: C)', 'Random Question #1 (Answer: F)', 'Random Question #1 (Answer: B)'],
  answers: ['a', 'c', 'f', 'b']
}, {
  questions: ['Random Question #1 (Answer: D)', 'Random Question #1 (Answer: C)', 'Random Question #1 (Answer: A)', 'Random Question #1 (Answer: E)'],
  answers: ['d', 'c', 'a', 'e']
}, {}, {}];

function Game(level) {
  this.level = level;
  this.score = 0;
  this.question = 1;

  this.nextQuestion = function() {
    this.question++;
  }

  this.increaseScore = function() {
    this.score++;
  }
}

function startLevel(level) {
  game = new Game(level);
  $('#levels').hide();
  $(`#level-quiz`).show();
  $('#level-info').show();
  play();
}

function play() {
  const currentLevel = game.level;
  const currentQuestion = game.question;
  if (currentQuestion - 1 < quiz[currentLevel - 1].questions.length) {
    $(`#level`).html(currentLevel);
    $(`#level-quiz #question-number`).html(currentQuestion);
    $(`#level-quiz #question`).html(`<h3>${quiz[currentLevel - 1].questions[currentQuestion-1]}</h3>`)
  } else {
    $('#end').show();
    $(`#level-quiz`).hide();
  }
}

function selectAnswer(answer) {
  const currentLevel = game.level;
  const currentQuestion = game.question;
  const correctAnswer = quiz[currentLevel - 1].answers[currentQuestion - 1];
  if (answer === correctAnswer) {
    game.increaseScore();
    updateScore();
  }
  game.nextQuestion();
  play();
}

function updateScore() {
  const currentScore = game.score;
  $(`#score`).html(currentScore);
}

function reset() {
  game = null;
  $('#levels').show();
  $('#level-info').hide();
  $('#end').hide();
  $('#score').html(0);
  $('#level-quiz').hide();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.levels-tiles,
.answers-tiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.levels-tiles .level-tile,
.answers-tiles .answer-tile {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fad0c4 0%, #ffd1ff 100%);
}

.level-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.reset {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="levels-tiles" id="levels">
  <h1> Choose a Level </h1>
  <button class="level-tile" onclick="startLevel(1);"> 1 </button>
  <button class="level-tile" onclick="startLevel(2);"> 2 </button>
  <button class="level-tile" onclick="alert('Not yet implemented');"> 3 </button>
  <button class="level-tile" onclick="alert('Not yet implemented');"> 4 </button>
</div>
<div class="level-info" id="level-info">
  <h1>Level <span id="level"></span></h1>
  <h1> Score: <span id="score">0</span></h1>
</div>
<div id="level-quiz">
  <div class="questions">
    <h2> Question <span id="question-number"></span></h2>
    <div id="question"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="answers-tiles">
    <h4>Choose an answer</h4>
    <button class="answer-tile" onclick="selectAnswer('a');"> A </button>
    <button class="answer-tile" onclick="selectAnswer('b');"> B </button>
    <button class="answer-tile" onclick="selectAnswer('c');"> C </button>
    <button class="answer-tile" onclick="selectAnswer('d');"> D </button>
    <button class="answer-tile" onclick="selectAnswer('e');"> E </button>
    <button class="answer-tile" onclick="selectAnswer('f');"> F </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="end">
  <h2> Thanks for playing!</h2>
</div>
<button class="reset" onclick="reset()"> Reset </button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate all of this! I'm still relatively early on my coding journey, and what I ended up doing so far is just creating setLevel method to do the first question, and having the answer in a global variable. The drawback is that the first question is automatically the "easy" level, so I'm going to study what you've sent and I think I'll learn a lot from it about how to implement this better. Thank you again so much!